# Encoding python dictionary into JSON using a schema

Tags: python, json, schema, jsonschema

I am struggling to encode json from a python dictionary. When using json.dumps on a dictionary there is no way to tell the function what objects and properties to map the dictionary keys and values to.

The result of the blind dump is that I end up with schemaless json with unique keys rather than a coherent json structure

```
import json

d = {
 "Laptop": {
            "sony": 1,
            "apple": 2,
            "asus": 5,
          },
 "Camera": {
            "sony": 2,
            "sumsung": 1,
            "nikon" : 4,
           },
}
with open("my.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(d,f)
```

Which returns

```
{"Laptop": {"sony": 1, "apple": 2, "asus": 5}, "Camera": {"sony": 2, "sumsung": 1, "nikon": 4}}
```

which looks like json, but has no schema at all.

i am looking to produce a json file more like this

```
{"devices": [
  {"device": {
      "deviceType": "Laptop",
      "deviceBrands": [
         {"deviceBrand": {
            "deviceBrandName": "sony",
            "deviceBrandCount": "1"
            },
         {"deviceBrand": {
            "deviceBrandName": "apple",
            "deviceBrandCount": "2"
            },
         {"deviceBrand": {
            "deviceBrandName": "asus",
            "deviceBrandCount": "5"
            }
      },
  {"device": {
      "deviceType": "Camera",
      "deviceBrands": [
         {"deviceBrand": {
            "deviceBrandName": "sony",
            "deviceBrandCount": "2"
            },
         {"deviceBrand": {
            "deviceBrandName": "sumsung",
            "deviceBrandCount": "1"
            },
         {"deviceBrand": {
            "deviceBrandName": "nikon",
            "deviceBrandCount": "5"
            }
     }
}
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: Create a function that takes the dictionary `d` and returns another dictionary formatted as your desired JSON output, then `json.dump` that dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the structure you want using a dictionary comprehension before calling `json.dump`:

```
output = {"devices": [
    {"device": {"deviceType": k, 
                "deviceBrands": [{"deviceBrand": {"deviceBrandName": k1, 
                                                  "deviceBrandCount": v1}
                                  } for k1, v1 in v.items()
                                 ]
                }
     } 
    for k,v in d.items()]}

with open("output.json","w") as f:
    json.dump(output,f)
```

###### output.json:

```
{
  "devices": [
    {
      "device": {
        "deviceType": "Laptop",
        "deviceBrands": [
          {
            "deviceBrand": {
              "deviceBrandName": "sony",
              "deviceBrandCount": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "deviceBrand": {
              "deviceBrandName": "apple",
              "deviceBrandCount": 2
            }
          },
          {
            "deviceBrand": {
              "deviceBrandName": "asus",
              "deviceBrandCount": 5
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "device": {
        "deviceType": "Camera",
        "deviceBrands": [
          {
            "deviceBrand": {
              "deviceBrandName": "sony",
              "deviceBrandCount": 2
            }
          },
          {
            "deviceBrand": {
              "deviceBrandName": "sumsung",
              "deviceBrandCount": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "deviceBrand": {
              "deviceBrandName": "nikon",
              "deviceBrandCount": 4
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```